# How to change a HTML image source in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So I have a div class with 5 images inline with each other:

```
<div class="image_line" >
    <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="img1" runat="server"/>
    <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="img2" runat="server"/> 
    <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="img3" runat="server"/> 
    <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="img4" runat="server"/>
    <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="img5" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change the source of each image 1 by 1 using their id.
I know you can do this in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById(img1).src = "StarOn.gif"
```

However I have no idea how to do this in c# asp.net. I cant find ant help on this matter.

EDIT: Made the changes suggested.

Comment: Are you using the old ASPX rendering engine, or are you using Razor in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: First of all, you need to change numeric id. You cannot use numerical ids like this. You need to change something like img1, img2 etc, which you can access in code behind and change src. If you want to change it using javascript, that's also possible.

Comment: so what would the code be to change the sources as thats what I dont know.

I tried:
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Coursework/StarOn.gif.png");

Whihc worled but instead of replacing the image it just took it away.

Answer (score -1):

For the old aspx rendering version:
You can use <%=(string var) %>
for example HTML:

```
 <img src="<%=img %>" />
```

.cs:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  public string img;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    img = "UploadedImages/9.gif";
  }
}
```

Comment: That would only work with the old ASPX rendering engine in WebForms.

Comment: since when is the change?

Comment: Razor has been around for over five years - since the release of MVC 3. Not many new projects are done in WebForms anymore.

Comment: my school are dumb we use visual studio 2010 and web forms good that they teach old tech :(

Comment: @AndersTornblad MVC project sample with good patterns and practices?